# Installing Visual Studio across multiple Operating Systems

Tags: windows, multi-boot, windows-registry, visual-studio

So I as many people have a copy of Windows 10 installed but I have Windows 7, I prefer Windows 10 over Windows 7 (it runs faster than my Windows 7 install). The problem is that I have a lot of IDE's on Windows 7 for example VS10, VS12, VS13, VS15, PHPStorm, Eclipse, IntelliJ, dotPeek...

Basically a lot of programming tools and resources and here is my Problem each install of Visual Studio is around 8-15GB's each, I don't have the best internet nor the disk space to reinstall them all.

So the question is at hand is it posible to copy registry entries over to Windows 10 and keep the IDE's on my Windows 7 install and use them over on my Windows 10 Install. I find myself having to jump between both Operating Systems and on my Windows 7 drive it takes 20-30 minutes to boot.

In a nutshell: Is it posible to use the Visual Studio on one Operating System and use it on another without having to reinstall it.

Comment: Its near impossible to move an installed program from one PC to another without reinstalling the program.

Comment: I meant the question in a way like keeping Visual Studio on one of the drives and accessing it from 2 different operating systems.

For example Drive C, D = Windows Installs and Drive G = Visual Studio install, Is it posible to place a registry entry to access Visual Studio from both operating systems to access Visual Studio without reinstalling.

Comment: Never tried it, it may make its own reg entries when you run the program exe from the other drive.

Comment: Would work by simply installing it two times to the same location. However, it may break after a single VS update.

Comment: So would it be best just to install both of them separately ?

Comment: Yes. VS is a fragile POS consisting of thousands of components. A single error in any of these may result in you being unable to use it until you reinstall Windows. It’s just not worth it.

Comment: Okay thanks for the note. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: What language are you coding in?  Maybe there's an alternative?  Eclipse can easily be made "portable" (and supports Mono for some .NET applications)

Comment: Ill just reinstall Visual Studio because i end up programming in c#, C++, JAVA, PHP and others in the same day, i have random projects. I get bored and start making something. So its best that i just install them again.

Comment: First, why don't you just upgrade Win7 to Win10 since it's free? You won't lose your programs/settings. If for some reason that's an issue, then use a remote desktop app like TightVNC to access the Win7 desktop from Win10.

Comment: @DiskCrasher I want to keep Windows 10 and Windows 7 Dual booted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work.

Visual Studio's install is not a portable one. It's very much integrated with the operating system where it's installed.